# Why object transfered to the a string?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
var added = this.checkList.filter(function(item) {
  console.log(typeof(item)); // line 1
  console.log(item);  // line 3
  return item.name == username;  // line 2
})
```

This is my code, the line 1 output Object exactly, and it have a name property
but why line 2 output the error

> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'.

I don't know what happened ?

Edit:
line 3 output:

> Object {name: "22", $key: "-KhEHRWZ-6981DJyygd4", $exists: function}
>   name
>   :
>   "22"
>   $exists
>   :
>   function ()
>   $key
>   :
>   "-KhEHRWZ-6981DJyygd4"
>   **proto**
>   :
>   Object

[image: 104 for the line3 105 for the line 2]

Comment: Without seeing any other code, it's impossible to know why this happened.

Comment: What is the value of `item`? Exactly what input are you using to execute this code?

Comment: please provide `console.log(item);`

Comment: add screen shot of the console

Comment: screen shot added, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a interface type definition as

```
export interface Items{
   name:string;
   id: number;
   ...
}


let added = this.checkList.filter(item:Items,item.name === username)
```